# Symfony1.4 embed i18n form into another i18n form

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

How to embed and render forms with i18n? For example: i want to embed Description form with i18n into Event form with i18n. How to do that? Right now my Event form renders without Description field.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in your form file:

```
public function configure()
{
  // ...

  $this->embedI18n(sfConfig::get('app_language_array'));
}
```

with your app.yml:

```
app:
  language:
    array:
      - en
      - pt
```